# How to get re-arrange the pandas dataframe based on frequency?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'c0': ['app','e','i','owl','u'],'c1': ['p','app','i','g',''],'c2': ['g','p','app','owl','']})
df


    c0  c1  c2
0   app p   g
1   e   app p
2   i   i   app
3   owl g   owl
4   u
```

I would like to align the rows based on frequency of items.

Required dataframe with quantities:

```
   c0   c1  c2
0   app app app
1   i   i   
2   owl     owl
3   e   p   p
4   u   g   g
```

## My attempt

```
all_cols = df.values.flatten()
all_cols = [i for i in all_cols if i]

freq = Counter(all_cols)
freq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get you this far:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c0': list('aeiou'),'c1': ['p','a','i','g',''],'c2': ['g','p','a','o','']})
allLetters = set(x for x in df.to_numpy().flatten() if x)
binaryIncidence = []
for letter in allLetters:
    binaryIncidence.append(tuple(int(letter in df[col].tolist()) for col in df.columns))
x = list(zip(allLetters, binaryIncidence))
x.sort(key=lambda y:(y[1], -ord(y[0])), reverse=True)
x = [[y[0] if b else '' for b in y[1]] for y in x]
df_results = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=df.columns)
print(df_results)
```

... with this output:

```
  c0 c1 c2
0  a  a  a
1  i  i
2  o     o
3  e
4  u
5     g  g
6     p  p
```

However, in the sample output from your question, you show 'e' getting paired up with 'p', 'p', and also 'u' getting paired up with 'g', 'g'. It's not clear to me how this selection would be made.

**UPDATE:** generalize to strings of arbitrary length

This will work not just with strings of length <=1 but of arbitrary length:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c0': ['app','e','i','owl','u'],'c1': ['p','app','i','g',''],'c2': ['g','p','app','owl','']})
allStrings = set(x for x in df.to_numpy().flatten() if x)
binaryIncidence = []
for s in allStrings:
    binaryIncidence.append(tuple(int(s in df[col].tolist()) for col in df.columns))
x = list(zip(allStrings, binaryIncidence))
x.sort(key=lambda y:(tuple(-b for b in y[1]), y[0]))
x = [[y[0] if b else '' for b in y[1]] for y in x]
df_results = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=df.columns)
print(df_results)
```

Output:

```
    c0   c1   c2
0  app  app  app
1    i    i
2  owl       owl
3    e
4    u
5         g    g
6         p    p
```

Comment: This is great (upvoted!)  but the values are only one characters, they are words.

Comment: @usermay14 Please see updated answer for the more general solution with strings of arbitrary length.

Comment: I updated it again to remove some extraneous code.